# Implement a color setting

Tags: android, kotlin, colors, sharedpreferences

In my application I have a settings screen that lets you change some colors of the application. I have defined the colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark on my color resource file, and I know that after the build is complete, it is impossible to change those values.

So the way I am doing this is by saving the color Integer in the SharedPreferences:

```
private val preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("my.package.name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

var primaryColor: Int
    get() = preferences.getInt("KEY_PRIMARY_COLOR", ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_primary))
    set(color) {
        val editor = preferences.edit()
        editor.putInt("KEY_PRIMARY_COLOR", color)
        editor.apply()
    }
```

And when the user start each activity, run a method to get the settings color and change the views color:

```
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        setSettings()
    }

    private fun setSettings() {
        val settings = Settings(this)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) window.statusBarColor = settings.secondaryColor
        toolbar_layout.setBackgroundColor(settings.primaryColor)

        add_button.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(settings.primaryColor)
        add_button.rippleColor = settings.secondaryColor

        //...
    }
}
```

My problem here is that doing like this, I have to repeat a lot of code for all activities. Also the activities are started with the "default" color when setContentView is run, and just after that I run the setSettings and I have to re-color all the views again.

Is there any way to do this? I am concerned with repeated code and performance issues. What should be the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a **BaseActivity** extend every activity from this class and place **setSettings** function in **BaseActivity**. In that way you will only write **setSettings** only once

Comment: I understand your aproach, the problem is that despite all activities having some equal views, like the toolbar_layout where it is present on all activities, some of them have different views, like the add_button is only present on some activities. Would this work if it is the case?

Comment: for getting color settings you can add that function in BaseActivity and fr setting views only for those activity you have to manage by adding new function